# dell 1720dn responds to ping but documents sit in print queue

Tags: networking, laser-printer

- Windows 7.
- Dell 1720DN laser printer.
- Will print test page when configured for USB port.
- TCP/IP set to 192.168.1.3 / 255.255.255.0.
- Responds to ping.
- Web server working.
- For test purposes I have both laptop and printer on a 192.168.1.0 router on their own.

When I try to print via network port the document goes to the print queue but goes no further.

[image: Port configuration]

[image: Port settings]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First check that no other device on the network has address 192.168.1.3. To test, switch the printer off and then try to ping it. If you get a reply, you have a duplicate address.

If the address is unique, then try resetting the printer to factory defaults, as follows (see [this link](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/peripherals/f/3528/t/18835573)):

```
Power off the printer
Open the front cover
Press and HOLD both the Cancel and Continue buttons
Continue to hold the buttons and power the printer on.
Continue to hold the buttons until all light cycling activity has stopped.
After the lights have stopped cycling (could take up to 30 seconds), release the buttons.
Close the front cover to complete the Factory Default reset process.
```

I have found that a factory reset solves many printer problems. After that you will need to give the printer the correct IP address again.